# Problema con metodo para pasar mi JTable a mi base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo un método el cual se debe encargar de pasar el JTable en el sistema a mi Base de datos, pero me sale la siguiente excepción:
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''53016001003' , 'Agua Purif Tempronics' , '0.0' , '0.0' , '220.16'

El metodo es el siguiente, no logro detectar el problema, tambien les compartire como tengo estructurada la tabla en mi bdd.

```
 public void guardarJTableBDD(JTable tablaDestino, Polizas ps, BancoInfo bancI) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        
            
                for (int i = 0; i < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    
                   
                    //Agregamos la informacion de mi JT1able generado
                    PreparedStatement pst = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO gen_exc (cuenta, nombre, cargoME, abonoME, cargo, abono, referencia, concepto, diario, segNeg, fecha, po ) VALUES ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?, ? , ? , ? ");
                    
                    pst.setString(1, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                    pst.setString(2, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                    pst.setString(5, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
                    pst.setString(6, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
                    pst.setString(7, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
                    pst.setString(8, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());
                    pst.setString(9, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());
                    pst.setString(10, tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());
                    pst.setDate(11, ps.getFecha());
                    pst.setInt(12, ps.getPo());

 pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

Tabla creada mi tabla en la bdd:

[image: tabla bdd]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? no logro detectar el problema, de antemano muchas gracias...

Comment: me parece que te falta los paréntesis en values (?,?,?,?)

Comment: Amigo tienes razón, algo tan sencillo y no me había dado cuenta, muchísimas gracias